# SoundCloud API returning 0 tracks despite user having tracks

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to get the tracks of specific users but for some users, even though they have tracks, the SoundCloud API return an empty list.

For example, the following user has 17 tracks as you can see from his `track_count`

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/1250904?client_id=XXXXXX
```

If I try to get his tracks it returns an empty list

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/1250904/tracks?client_id=XXXXXX
```

Is it possible for users to make their songs not available via API? Is there a field on the user that can distinguish this?

Comment: This sounds like a question for SoundCloud's support team.

Comment: @tristan Their support team answers questions using StackOverflow - https://developers.soundcloud.com/support

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know that; thanks.  That's one of the better "we'll crowdsource and get free work" implementations I've seen.

Comment: SoundCloud shouldn't be doing this.  See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: @YinYang did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very interesting.  Using a normal CLIENT_ID I generated myself, I get the same results you do.  Additionally, if I try to hit the API for information about a specific track, I get a 403 Forbidden error:

```
HTTP GET https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/149151252.json?client_id=XXXXXX
```

There could be a few reasons why this is occurring:

1. The user has hit their download limit for all of their tracks.
2. The user has disabled oEmbed, causing the API requests to 403 (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9079862/2415822)).
3. The user has somehow managed to block normal API access to their tracks.

I'm leaning on choice 3 here.  I've done some testing with some other CLIENT_IDs in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29914622/2415822) trying the CLIENT_ID used by the youtube-dl application.  Using their `_IPHONE_CLIENT_ID`, I was able to see information for all 17 tracks.  If my understanding of that key is correct, it is a master API key used by SoundCloud for their iOS application, which would explain why that key works and others do not.

This user must have some setting enabled to block standard API access to their tracks.

Comment: That's is a very interesting find. I just hope the `_IPHONE_CLIENT_ID` works in the long run as well.

Comment: I should note that it is against SoundClould's TOS to use someone else's API key or to reverse-engineer their endpoints.  So you don't want to rely on someone else's API key for your application.

Comment: I know this is a bit old at this point, but I've hit this issue with Soundcloud's APIs and that `_IPHONE_CLIENT_ID` no longer works (and isn't really a viable solution).
I did some testing with a Soundcloud account and I could find no combination of privacy settings that would allow a track to show up in the UI but not in the API return. I also emailed api@soundcloud.com, but received no response.
I don't suppose any of you have found documentation of different API key access levels?

Comment: @rifflock Yeah, looks like that old iOS key isn't working anymore.  Try one of the newer keys in [this issue](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/12376) or grab it from SoundCloud's app.js web player.