# Soundcloud API stopped returning tracks

Tags: soundcloud

Recently, as in the past couple months, Soundcloud has stopped returning tracks for **lots** of artists using the API endpoint:

`http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{USER_ID}/tracks?client_id={CLIENT_ID}`

Why is this?

I am hoping for an answer to this by Soundcloud's support team, as 
I found the answer to [SoundCloud API returning 0 tracks despite user having tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485387/soundcloud-api-returning-0-tracks-despite-user-having-tracks) unsatisfying.

Comment: can you give a user id example? then we could test it too.

Comment: For example [Sam Feldt](https://soundcloud.com/samfeldt) has this issue.

https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=https://soundcloud.com/samfeldt?client_id=... -> https://api.soundcloud.com/users/57447226?client_id=... 

Track count 63 at time of writing. Then https://api.soundcloud.com/users/57447226/tracks?client_id=... and you get and empty result. If you try a specific track using the resolve, you get a 403.

https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=https://soundcloud.com/samfeldt/sam-feldt-shadows-of-love-feat-heidi-rojas-extended-mix&client_id=...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting a 403 error because the right holder disabled API access to the tracks. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac/36529330#36529330), hope that it is more satisfying.

> SoundCloud emailed back saying they have introduced an option for right holders to disable all API access to tracks by default, returning this 403 error when requested. They also said it's understandable that this is a confusing feature, and that they hope to make it more clear.

And seems that you only get the 403 on specific tracks, but on the /tracks endpoint you just get an empty result, as I've tested for [another question about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688041/soundcloud-playlist-tracks-is-empty/36697558).

Comment: I just found a response of the soundcloud tech lead on this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626513/soundcloud-api-json-track-count-does-not-match-profile-track-count 

Yep -- there's many reasons that a track might not show up to you. It could be taken down by the rightsholder of the track, made private or deleted by the uploader, or (and this is the tricky one) blocked in certain territories. Calculating the policies of all of the tracks of a user every time it is fetched isn't quite feasible, so sometimes this number will be inaccurate – nickf Apr 14 at 22:37

Answer (score 0):

I also can confirm this problem if I try to resolve a playlist I get an empty tracks array.[image]