# SoundCloud Playlist tracks is empty

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to get the playlist information fromSoundCloud HTTP API and I'm getting the playlist information and the track_count return the right number for tracks that I have in the playlist but the tracks is empty.

I have tried the following links: https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/215861217
The track_count returns for this playlist is 2.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably related to a [change in the settings from the soundcloud developers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36529330/244748). If you try to get the track information of the tracks of your playlist you get a 403 forbidden:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106185859?client_id=...
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/243762135?client_id=...

> SoundCloud emailed back saying they have introduced an option for right holders to disable all API access to tracks by default, returning this 403 error when requested. They also said it's understandable that this is a confusing feature, and that they hope to make it more clear.

These type of questions [should not be handled on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company/255746#255746), but unfortunately that is the only way to contact the soundcloud developers [according to their documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/support). I've tried reaching out to them on [twitter](https://twitter.com/soundclouddev), but so far no response.

Comment: So, there is no solution for this issue. The API was changed and there is no way to get the playlist tracks information.

Comment: Nope. I just found a comment of the tech lead from soundcloud on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36626513/soundcloud-api-json-track-count-does-not-match-profile-track-count 

there's many reasons that a track might not show up to you. It could be taken down by the rightsholder of the track, made private or deleted by the uploader, or (and this is the tricky one) blocked in certain territories. Calculating the policies of all of the tracks of a user every time it is fetched isn't quite feasible, so sometimes this number will be inaccurate – nickf Apr 14 at 22:37

Comment: Yeah, this is frustrating issue.  I'm shocked that they don't seem aware of how much this impacts the user experience.

Comment: It's doesn't make sens, In my playlist I have 2 songs of Kygo and Tiesto. There is no blocking of these songs (I can play them via SC) and I have done the same thing in YouTube and I can get the tracks information so SC reasons doesn't make sens. I think this is API bug.

Comment: NoamMaoz I wish it was the case. But by comment of @nickf and also other comments tell me that it's intentional. You can playback the file via the soundcloud website, but the API gives a 403 forbidden. And the reason for that I can't give you, but probably it's because API access to the track is forbidden.

Comment: @NoamMaoz No, it depends on the tracks contained in the playlist. Some playlists are lacking just some tracks (and not all as in your case), for example the one named in this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755039/soundcloud-api-not-returning-all-tracks-from-playlist-through-python "Using it on this playlist: https://soundcloud.com/michiel-tammeling/sets/icecubes which contains 13 tracks, however the code only returns 11."

Comment: thanks for the information nut the my playlist contains only 2 songs as follows: 1. Kygo — Ed Sheeran & Passenger - No Diggity vs. Thrift Shop (Kygo Remix) 2.Tiësto — Tiësto & Oliver Heldens ft. Natalie La Rose. I don't think that these songs are blocked in any case. Moreover, in YouTube you are getting the reason for the block and here there is nothing.

Comment: @NoamMaoz: I checked your two tracks in my first answer. Those 2 are blocked. But yes, it's unfortunate that Soundcloud doesn't provide information about why it's blocked.