# How to get a soundcloud master API key?

Tags: soundcloud

I have a same issue for this : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485387/soundcloud-api-returning-0-tracks-despite-user-having-tracks/33502376)

According to answer, master key can response all data for my request.

Actually, I already have tested with master key : [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/commit/64bb5187f53caea0e6067434c95da60284eef2ea) and I can get all data(specific user's track list).

So I wonder how to get Soundcloud master API key. (I already have normal API key. but I can't get a specific user's track list)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  SoundCloud's master key is for their apps, not for anyone who registers an application.  No API client can or should have a master key.  The developers of youtube-dl have managed to reverse engineer the iOS app to get the master key from there, but that is a violation of SoundClould's [Terms of Service](https://soundcloud.com/terms-of-use).

My answer on the linked question went into detail on the different types of responses that are returned from the server using different keys.  This approach was purely experimental and should not be used in production.